# Resize form by its child

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am doing a Windows Forms Application and I need to change Form2 size by Form1. I already tried it and didn't work.

```
Control control = this.Parent;
control.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(490, 380);
///// 

Parent.control.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(490, 380);   
///
Form2 main = new Form2();
main.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(490, 380);
```

Anyone could help?

Comment: This `Form2 main = new Form2();` creates a new Form2 but doesn't show it. This  `main.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(490, 380);` changes its size, but it is still not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resize the main form when the second form is resized you have to add an event handler to the resize event:

```
Form second = new Form ();
second.Resize += (object sender, EventArgs e2) => this.Size = second.Size;
```

If you want to change the size of the main form when the user clicks a button or something else happens, you have to store a reference to the main form (e.g. as constructor parameter):

```
private readonly Form _parent;

public SecondForm (Form parent)
{
    _parent = parent; 
}

public void SomethingHappend ()
{
    _parent.Size = this.Size;
}
```